# How can I implement phpCAS in laravel 5.*

Tags: laravel, phpcas

I'm almost new to Laravel. I need to use `phpCAS` in my project in Laravel 5 but I don't know how to do it. I've have seen the documentation in Github about subfission. It explains how to install it but I don't know how to use it in my project. Can someone show me an example of its usage? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a notion of a "user" already. If you call phpCAS's `forceAuthentication()` method, I think you can then send a client to the CAS login page. Once the client has authenticated, you should be able to retrieve the username or something via the `$_SESSION` variable. Once you have that, you could look up the corresponding User model and manually authenticate them.

Try looking at [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) on authentication.